# Any Idea's why this Google App Script filter will not properly filter

Tags: google-apps-script, filter

I have written the following code

---

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var tabProgram = "Test";
  var TabUpcomingTransposed = "Data"
  var UpcomingTransposedss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(TabUpcomingTransposed);
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();


  //Get array of data to filter if Date dropdown is changed
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 4 && activeCell.getRow() == 2  && ss.getSheetName() === tabProgram){

    //get Data in an array form sheet
    var ArrayofPrograms = UpcomingTransposedss.getRange(2, 1,UpcomingTransposedss.getLastRow() , UpcomingTransposedss.getLastColumn()) .getValues();
    //Logger.log(ArrayofPrograms);

    //Get Date from dropdown
    var Program_date = Utilities.formatDate(activeCell.getValue(), "GMT+1", "dd-MMM-yyyy");
    Logger.log(Program_date);


    //filter on array by selected date
    var ProgramsFiltered = ArrayofPrograms.filter(function(item){
      /return true;
      //return false;

      var filter_date =  Utilities.formatDate(item[0], "GMT+1", "dd-MMM-yyyy");

      if (filter_date.valueOf() == Program_date.valueOf()) {
        Browser.msgBox('Test', 'True', Browser.Buttons.OK); 
        return true;
      } else {
        Browser.msgBox('Test', 'False', Browser.Buttons.OK); 
        return false; 
      }
    });

    Browser.msgBox('Test', 'Filter Done', Browser.Buttons.OK); 
    Logger.log(ProgramsFiltered); 


  } else {
    //Nothing
  }

}
```

---

If I run that code I get one popup message saying "Filter Done" as expected and when I view logs I get an array with all items that are in the initial array.

If I comment out `return true;` I get one popup message saying "Filter Done"and when I view the logs I get an emprty array "[]"

If I comment out `return true;` and `return false;` lines, I get 15 popup messages corresponding to the 15 items in the original test array. Some will say true, some will say false. The "Filter done" popup will not appear and when I go to the view logs it is empty.

Any ideas why this will not work???

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve].

Comment: Your example code is incomplete.

Comment: Please share your sample data. I've tried your code and I can't recreate this issue.

Comment: I put this google sheet together that has the code in it that is not working. here is the link. thanks for any help.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z75ND9rm0tY4Zgd4-fdL0wzyc0-qO5E6kaxMzWXrPSI/copy

Comment: FWIW, `var ArrayofPrograms` is "A2:D11" because you start on row 2 but use `UpcomingTransposedss.getLastRow()` for the number of rows. The number of rows should be `UpcomingTransposedss.getLastRow()-1`.

Comment: It will work if you adjust the number of rows (as mentioned above). "Some will say true, some will say false", actually ONE will say true and the rest will say false because only one will be a match to data.

Comment: Your browser button set of "Yes_NO" isn't very helpful. `OK` &/or `OK_CANCEL` might be more helpful, though you would still have to evaluate them and provide the code to execute as one or other options is selected.

Comment: Thanks Tedinoz works like a charm now. The "yes_no" was just to let me see what was happening when the code was running. Your right "ok" would be logically better but are not being left in the final code. Also I did not use the same data that I did in my main file so again sorry for the confusion. In the test file only one would come back true as you said. Thanks again for your help.